# C# enum in public variable .NET

Tags: c#, .net, class, variables, enums

For my program, I created a new class called `FinishedPiece` with a number of public variables available to my main program. For example:

```
class FinishedPiece
{
    private double _PieceLength;
    public double PieceLength
    {
         get { return _PieceLength; }
         set { _PieceLength = value; }
    }
}
```

This all works fine, because then I can declare a new `FinishedPiece` and add properties:

```
FinishedPiece piece = new FinishedPiece();
piece.PieceLength = 48.25;
```

My question is, how do the same with an `enum`? If I do

```
public enum Cut
{
    Angle = 0,
    Straight = 1,
    AngleThenStraight = 2,
    StraightThenAngle = 3
};
```

then I'd like to change it something like this: `piece.Cut = Cut.Angle;` but I can only change it by declaring a new `FinishedPiece.Cut` object:

```
FinishedPiece.Cut cut = new FinishedPiece.Cut();
cut = FinishedPiece.Cut.Angle;
```

How do I make an `enum` available inside a variable so I can do `piece.Cut = Cut.Angle`? To me it would make sense to do something like this, but it doesn't appear to work.

```
public int Cut
{
    get { return _Cut; }
    set { _Cut = value; }

}

private enum _Cut
{
    Angle = 0,
    Straight = 1,
    AngleThenStraight = 2,
    StraightThenAngle = 3
};
```

Thanks in advance! Let me know if my question is unclear and I'll try to help as best as I can.

Comment: `FinishedPiece` doesn't contain a public variable. It contains a private variable, which backs a public *property*.

Comment: _Cut is not an int.  The public and private must be the same type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How do I make an enum available inside a variable so I can do
>   piece.Cut = Cut.Angle?

Just define another property of type `Cut` in your class like:

```
public Cut Cut { get; set; }
```

Then you can do:

```
FinishedPiece piece = new FinishedPiece();
piece.PieceLength = 48.25;
piece.Cut = Cut.Angle; //like this
```

So your class would like like:

```
class FinishedPiece
{
    private double _PieceLength;
    public double PieceLength
    {
        get { return _PieceLength; }
        set { _PieceLength = value; }
    }

    public Cut Cut { get; set; }
}
```

Consider using [Auto-Implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), if you have only simple `set` and `get`

Comment: +1 for beating me to the punch by minutes and not seconds, and for suggesting AIPs. :0

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I took your advice about AIPs. Good to know! I always like to shorten my code any way that I can and that certainly does.

Comment: @gnarlybracket, you are welcome, just remember that Auto implemented properties use a private backing field internally. But it does shorten the code

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
class FinishedPiece
{
    private double _PieceLength;
    public double PieceLength
    {
        get { return _PieceLength; }
        set { _PieceLength = value; }
    }
    private Cut _Cut;
    public Cut Cut
    {
        get { return _Cut; }
        set { _Cut = value; }
    }
}
public enum Cut
{
    Angle = 0,
    Straight = 1,
    AngleThenStraight = 2,
    StraightThenAngle = 3
};
```

Then you can do:

```
var piece = new FinishedPiece();
piece.Cut = Cut.AngleThenStraight;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    private enum Cut
    {
        //if you dont want to use any of these values as defaults 
        //just add another value and in your class private member
        //assign it like for example a value called None
        Angle = 0,
        Straight = 1,
        AngleThenStraight = 2,
        StraightThenAngle = 3
    };

    public class FinishedPiece
    {
        //give it a default,if like stated in the enum you dont want
        //any of those values create a None and place it here as default.
        private Cut cutObj = Cut.Angle;

        public Cut CutObj
        {
            get { return cutObj; }
            set { cutObj = value; }
        }
    }
```

Then in your calling code...

```
FinishedPiece piece = new FinishedPiece();
//if you dont want the default change it...
piece.CutObj = Cut.Straight;
```